# less stacks using StackWalk64

Tags: windows, stack, trace, dbghelp

I built test.exe which will crash and generate .dmp file using MinidumpWriteDump, and parser.exe is used to read and print information from that dmp file.

In parser.exe I use StackWalk64 to get all stack traces of all threads in that dmp file.
But now I found that I can only get less stacks than that visual studio did.

I've tried all solutions I could find in google、stackoverflow、codeproject, nothing changed.

The following is what parser.exe do:

1. SymInitialize
2. MiniDumpReadDumpStream to read all information
3. SymLoadModuleEx & SymFindFileInPath to load pdb/exe/dll specified in .dmp file
4. Initialize STACKFRAME64 and call StackWalk64 in loop.

I want to know how to get the same count of stack as visual studio.
I could paste more code here if needed.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

StackWalk64 isn't robust enough to follow the full stack trace, especially through frames that have been optimized. (For example, see this stackoverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12280472/stackwalk64-does-not-work-with-release-build)).

The best approach is to actually use the debug engine supplied with [WinDbg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551063%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Here are a couple of blog posts that show how to use the debug engine API:

- [Getting the Stack from a .DMP File (Automating Crash Dump Analysis
  Part 2)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joshpoley/archive/2008/06/02/getting-the-stack-from-a-dmp-file-automating-crash-dump-analysis-part-2.aspx)
- [MiniDumps and "Bad" Stacks](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joshpoley/archive/2008/11/10/minidumps-and-bad-stacks.aspx)